# Simple way to unit test a lazy load property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ioc-container, abstraction

I'm somewhat of a newbie in unit testing. Stumbled upon a problem of unit testing a lazy load property and wondering if there is a simple solution to that:

```
private SubscriptionType _subscriptionType;
public SubscriptionType SubscriptionType
{
    get
    {
        if (_subscriptionType == null ||_subscriptionType.SubscriptionTypeId != this.SubscriptionTypeId)
        {
            if (this.SubscriptionTypeId !=0)
                _subscriptionType = SubscriptionType.Load(this.SubscriptionTypeId);
        }

        return _subscriptionType;
    }
}
```

I need to test logic in the property (if statements) and not the actual SubscriptionType load functionality - seems like the most obvious approach here would probably be to abstract SubscriptionType.Load and use some type of IoC to replace with a mock method.
I'm just wondering if there are any simpler ways to avoid this kind of refactoring - seems like somewhat of an overengineering just to write a correct unit test case.
Your thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Look at the Lazy<T> class in .NET 4.  Using that, you'll have way less code - probably nothing even worth unit testing

Comment: What are you trying to test? The fact that property contains correct data or the fact that it is loaded in lazy manner?

Comment: Trying to test the logic that it invokes Load when conditions are met and bypasses the Load otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you want to use TypeMock Isolator or Moles you'll have to hide the Load method behind an interface and inject that into the class. There's no way around it, but you'll not only be doing it for the sake of testability. Usually you also tend to get better separation of concerns out of such  a refactoring.